# Calculate $\operatorname{Hom}_{\Bbb Z}(\Bbb Z_6,\Bbb R^*\oplus \Bbb C^*)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $\Bbb R^*=\Bbb R-\{0\}$ (non-zero real numbers) and $\Bbb C^*=\Bbb C-\{0\}$ (non-zero complex numbers) be multiplicative groups. Is  this equality true?

$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\Bbb Z}(\Bbb Z_6,\Bbb R^*\oplus \Bbb C^*)=0.$$

We know that $$\operatorname{Hom}_{\Bbb Z}(\Bbb Z_6,\Bbb R^*\oplus \Bbb C^*)\underset{\Bbb Z}{\cong} \operatorname{Hom}_{\Bbb Z}(\Bbb Z_6,\Bbb R^*)\oplus \operatorname{Hom}_{\Bbb Z}(\Bbb Z_6, \Bbb C^*)$$ as $\Bbb Z$-modules.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider a primitive third root of unity $\omega\in \Bbb C^\ast$ and think about how the element $(-1,\omega)\in \Bbb R^\ast\oplus \Bbb C^\ast$ might be used.

Answer (score 1):

What about the function

$$\phi:\Bbb Z_6\to\Bbb R^*\oplus\Bbb C^*\;,\;\;\phi(k\pmod 6):=(-1^k,1)\;\;?$$

You can even write down specifically all the 6 different values of this function and check it is a group homomorphism.

You probably can find more...

Hint: Remember that $\,\displaystyle{Tor\left(\Bbb R^*\oplus\Bbb C^*\right)\cong C_2\times \Bbb R/\Bbb Z}\,$

Comment: $Tor$? Which $Tor$?

Comment: Like "Torsion" subgroup...